# lsf awk command quotes

Tags: awk, lsf

When I run this command in the bash terminal it works:

```
awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' /user/dnaiel/test.txt > /user/dnaiel/sum.txt
```

But when I run this:

```
bsub -q priority -R'rusage[mem=2000]' -oo bin${count}.out -eo bin${count}.err \
"awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' /user/dnaiel/test.txt > /user/dnaiel/sum.txt"
```

It does not work.  I also tried changing ' to \' but also does not work.

I get the following errors:
for the first case:

```
awk: { sum +=  } END { print sum }
awk:           ^ syntax error
```

for the case I used \'

```
awk: '{
awk: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

Any ideas where I am messing up with the syntax?  I am quite puzzled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notice how the `$1` has disappeared in the error message?

```
awk: { sum +=  } END { print sum }
awk:           ^ syntax error
```

This is because in shell, when you quote something FIRST with dbl-quotes, as you have done with

```
bsub -q priority -R'rusage[mem=2000]' -oo bin${count}.out -eo bin${count}.err \
"awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' /user/dnaiel/test.txt > /user/dnaiel/sum.txt"
```

any ${var} references are expanded to their value. The single-quotes have lost their magic power to prevent variable expansion when they are inside a dbl-quoted string.

How to fix, escape your `$`s. not sure what bsub is, but this should do it:

```
bsub -q priority -R'rusage[mem=2000]' -oo bin${count}.out -eo bin${count}.err \
"awk '{ sum += \$1 } END { print sum }' /user/dnaiel/test.txt > /user/dnaiel/sum.txt"
# -------------^^^
```

IHTH

Comment: Glad to be your second set of eyes. Good luck!